# backdrop-filter не применяется к блоку

Tags: reactjs, tailwindcss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пробовал и inline стилями дать и так не применяется[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Первый сайт в Яндексе по запросу "backdrop filter blur не работает": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70984828/why-does-css-blur-backdrop-filter-not-work-in-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного видоизменю пример из [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70984828/why-does-css-blur-backdrop-filter-not-work-in-chrome), который я вам написал в комментариях.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

@supports ((-webkit-backdrop-filter: none) or (backdrop-filter: none)) {
  .sticky {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sticky">
    <h1>This is a header</h1>
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam asperiores at autem, dicta dignissimos ex, fugiat fugit harum id itaque nulla odio perferendis quasi qui similique! Doloribus nesciunt quaerat tempora.
  </p>
  <div style="height: 400px"></div>
</body>
```

В примере видно, что `blur` никак не влияет на сплошной цвет за блоком у которого установлено свойство `backdrop-filter`, но текст размывается.